# $n$-th power of a complex non-diagonalizable $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a complex matrix in the form $$ \begin{pmatrix} a-ib & ic \\ -ic & a+ib \end{pmatrix}  $$ which is not diagonalizable according to my understanding. How to calculate the $n$-th power of this matrix? Can we use eigenvalue decomposition or Cayley-Hamilton theorem on this? Or is there a way to approximate the polynomials?

Comment: If it’s not diagonalizable, you shoul try Jordan normal form, to make it as close to diagonal as posible, and take the power of that.

Comment: or is it okay to approximate the elements of nth power matrix by using chebyshev polynomials?

Comment: I don’t know about that, but you can write elements of matrix in polar form, which is quite nice

Comment: That's peculiar, I'd have thought that was diagonalisable, at least for most values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: is it diagnonalizable?? based on the fact that it's not Hermitian made me think it's not diagonalizable.

Comment: The values of a,b and c can vary. for example, a=cosh(gL) which varies with g and L. This is a generalized matrix.

Comment: There are plenty of non-Hermitian matrices which are diagonalisable. For a start, for this matrix to be non-diagonalisable, its eigenvalues must be equal. What's the condition on $a$, $b$ and $c$ for this to hold?

Comment: eigenvalues become equal only when $ b= \pm c$.

Comment: this matrix being not hermitian, skew-hermitian does not mean that it's diagonalizable unless and until eigenvalues become equal? is that the only concern to check its diagonalizability?

Comment: it is not a normal matrix. is it still diagonalizable? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $$X^2-2aX+a^2+b^2-c^2$$
To be nondiagonalizable, this would have to equal $(X-r)^2$ for some $r$. Examining the linear term, $r$ would have to be $a$. Examining the constant term, $b^2$ would have to equal $c^2$. So as noted in the comments, $c=\pm b$ is required for this to be not diagonalizable. And in that situation, $a$ is the one eigenvalue.

So now consider
$$M-aI=i\begin{pmatrix} -b & c \\ -c & b \end{pmatrix}$$
Its kernel is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ b \end{pmatrix}$. And $\frac{-i}{2b}\begin{pmatrix} -c \\ b \end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} c \\ b \end{pmatrix}$.

It follows from the usual diagonalization/Jordan-normalization process that
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

and then

$$M^n=\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
$$M^n=\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a^n & na^{n-1} \\ 0 & a^n \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c & \frac{ic}{2b} \\ b & -\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer. At the end you have decomposed the matrix and taken the nth power by considering the non-diagonalizable case right? Is this the final solution for the nth power of this matrix? You have considered the Jordan normal form because the matrix has a non-diagonalizable case right?

Comment: I am assuming you are only interested in the non-diagonalizable case because of the question's wording. So starting with the second paragraph, the assumption is $c=-b$. And yes that is a way to get a power of $M$. If you want to also consider the diagonalizable case, that will work out differently. There will be two eigenvalues, $a\pm\sqrt{c^2-b^2}$ in the diagonal of the center matrix, and the conjugating matrix will be something different.

Comment: i need to consider both the cases. From what i understood, for the diagonalizable case, eigenvalue decomposition can be performed and nth power can be taken that way and for non-diagonalizable case, the answer provided by you is the solution right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: Well thank you so much for your insightful comments. Then there shall be two expressions for nth power of this matrix considering the two cases. This is exactly what I wanted to confirm. Initially I thought there can be a common solution for nth power for both the cases  (by making it nearly diagonalizableusing Jordan form). Thank you again.

Comment: There is a significant error in what I posted. Stand by for a correction.

Comment: OK, I corrected an error or two where I had oversimplified things.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you suggest a good reference to study about the Jordan normal form? I haven't worked with the concept before.

Comment: Linear algebra textbooks should have a section or more about it. Also there is the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).